# AWS CDK Issue with Appsync

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-appsync

```py
import this
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import (
Duration,
Stack,
aws_iam as iam,
aws_appsync as appsync,
aws_dynamodb as dynamodb,
aws_lambda as lamb
)

class CdkStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        
        api = appsync.GraphqlApi(self, "Api",
        name="demo",
        schema=appsync.Schema.from_asset('graphql/schema.graphql'),
        authorization_config=appsync.AuthorizationConfig(
            default_authorization=appsync.AuthorizationMode(
                authorization_type=appsync.AuthorizationType.IAM
            )
        ),
        xray_enabled=True
    )
```

When I run 'cdk synth' I get the error --> AttributeError: module 'aws_cdk.aws_appsync' has no attribute 'GraphqlApi'. Did you mean: 'CfnGraphQLApi'?

However, GraphqlApi is an attribute in the pypi documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the `GraphqlApi` construct in the [aws_cdk.aws_appsync_alpha](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-appsync-alpha-readme.html) package.

Not-yet-stable APIs are in separate "alpha" packages in CDK v2.  The Appsync constructs are split between 2 packages, `aws_cdk.aws_appsync_alpha` for "experimental" APIs, and `aws_cdk.aws_appsync` for stable APIs.